# Understanding Folland 3.9 Proposition: Radon-Nikodym Derivative

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

Suppose that $\nu$ is a $\sigma$-finite signed measure and $\mu$, $\lambda$ are $\sigma$-finite measures on $(X,M)$ such that $\nu<<\mu$ and $\mu << \lambda$.
a. If g $\in L_1(\mu)$ then 
$\int g d\nu=\int g \frac{d\nu}{d\mu}d\mu$

Folland's Proof:
By considering $\nu+$ and $\nu-$ separately we may assume $\nu \geq 0$. The equation $\int g d\nu=\int g \frac{d\nu}{d\mu}d\mu$ is true when g=$X_E$ (indicator function on E), by definition of $d\nu/d\mu$.

**I don't understand why this is true for g=$X_E$ by the definition of $d\nu/d\mu$? Could someone explain why this is true?**

This is what I know:
the decomposition $\nu=\rho+\lambda$ where $\lambda$ is mutually singular to $\mu$ and $\rho << \mu$ is called the Lebesgue decomposition of $\nu$ with respect to $\mu$.
In the case where $\nu << \mu$, we have $d\nu=fd\mu$ for some f, $\nu(E)=\int_E f d\mu$ for all E and denote f by $d\nu/d\mu$. I guess thus we have $\nu(E)=\int_E \frac{d\nu}{d\mu} d\mu$, which I guess represents $d\nu=\frac{d\nu}{d\mu} d\mu$.

All the notation is very confusing, so I'm very confused why when g=$X_E$ we can say $d\nu=\frac{d\nu}{d\mu}d\mu$ in the integral in the proof.
Any help would be much appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By **definition**, $d\nu / d\mu$ is a $\mu$-locally integrable function for which

$$\int_A \frac{d\nu}{d\mu}\, d\mu = \nu(A)$$

for all $\mu$-measurable sets $A$. So if we take $g = \chi_E$, then

$$\int_X  g \frac{d\nu}{d\mu}\, d\mu = \int_X \chi_E \frac{d\nu}{d\mu} \, d\mu = \int_E \frac{d\nu}{d\mu} \, d\mu = \nu(E)$$

agreeing with the fact that $\int_X g d\nu = \int_E d\nu = \nu(E)$.

Note that the singular part of the measure you refer to is zero in this context, because you're assuming that $\nu$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $\mu$.

Comment: Are the conditions for the radon-nikodym derivative to exist that $\nu$ and $\mu$ are absolutely continuous, or do they also need to be mutually singular?

Comment: The typical assumption is that $\nu$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $\mu$. See, e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon–Nikodym_theorem#Radon–Nikodym_derivative).

Comment: is$ \int_E d\nu=\nu(E)$ in true only for positive measures (not necessarily signed)?

Answer (score 1):

Since $\nu \ll \mu$, Radon-Nikodym states that

$$
\nu(E) = \int_E \frac{d\nu}{d\mu}d\mu \tag{1}
$$

Now, note that for any measure $\lambda$ we have that $\lambda(E) = \int\chi_Ed\lambda$ and so

$$
\int\chi_E d\nu  = \nu(E) = \int_E \frac{d\nu}{d\mu}d\mu = \int\chi_E\frac{d\nu}{d\mu}d\mu. \tag{2}
$$

Now, just let $g = \chi_E$ and replace it in $(2)$.

Comment: So it is true that $\nu(E)= \int X_E d\nu$ even though $\nu$ is signed.  Is this true for all measures? Also are the conditions for the Radon-Nikodym derivative to exist that $\nu << \mu$.  Do we also have to have that they are mutually singular?

Comment: Here $\nu$ is not signed because of the initial simplifications that were made. Iirc with the hypothesis you have (both $\sigma$-finite) you only need that $\nu \ll \mu$ to use Radon - Nykodim. I am not certain about mutual singularity (by the way, have a look at Lebesgue's decomposition theorem which is related).

Comment: Hi but the hypothesis states that $\nu$ is a signed $\sigma$-finite  measure. Oh but we are considering $\nu$>0?

Comment: Yes, in the first line of the proof you cite we assume $\nu \geq 0$. 

I think the equality should hold regardless, splitting $\nu$ into positivity and negativity sets via Hahn's decomposition, but I am not one hundred percent certain.